# QTableWidget signal after table items sorted

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

i want to get some function called after `QTableWidet` sorting indicator changed and the table's data being sorted.

i used `sortIndicatorChanged` signal of horizontal header but it's being called before data has been sorted.

```
class MyDialog(Ui_MyWindowDialog, QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(*args)
        super(MyDialog, self).setupUi(self)
        header_view = self.my_tbl_widget.horizontalHeader()
        header_view.sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self.afterTableDataSorted)

    def afterTableDataSorted(self, col, order):
        'this is called before table data being sorted'
        # my logic after table being sorted
```

Comment: Please, include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you indicate that the sortIndicatorChanged signal is called before the sorting?

Comment: @eyllanesc because it is used to indicate sorting order or column chaned and it is the only signal i've found. It is called before sorting. you can test it via QMessageBox.

Comment: In the following link is my test, and each time you sort the item is printed in the first row of the column pressed and matches the item that is observed after the sorting: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/ff8c43f1536a30003b8593ec27dd9bba

Comment: @eyllanesc i changed the first line of `afterTableDataSorted` to `QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, '', 'called')`. then after i click ok button table data will be sorted.